# Не пойму логику программы С++

Tags: c++, операторы, инкремент

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 10;

    std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;

    int c = a++;
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;

    c = ++b;
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Консоль выдает следующие значения:**

```
10 10
11 10 10
11 11 11
```

*Не могу понять следующие: Если во втором случае переменная `c` принимает значения `a++` то она должна во втором случае выдать `c` как 11 но в консоли `10` . Почему?*

Answer (score 7):

```
int c = a++;
```

означает: "*присвоить переменной `c` значение `a`, а **потом** увеличить значение `a` на 1*. Короче, `a++` увеличивает `a` на 1, но вот возвращает значение **до** увеличения. Т.е. это, грубо говоря, можно записать так:

```
int operator++(int)
{
    int tmp = *this;
    *this += 1;
    return tmp;
}
```

На то он и **пост**фиксный инкремент - в отличие от **пре**фиксного, который

```
c = ++b;
```

присваивает переменной `c` значение увеличенного `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Все просто:

```
int c = a++;
```

эквивалентно

```
int c = a;
a += 1;
```

A

```
c = ++b;
```

эквивалентно

```
b += 1;
c = b;
```